# Extract domain or subdomain PHP

Tags: php

I need to extract either domain or 1st level subdomain from the link with regex

```
www.google.com -> google.com
www.maps.google.com -> maps.google.com
www.dev.maps.google.com - > maps.google.com
www.dev.maps.google.com/show/maps - > maps.google.com
```

I know how to do extract just the domain, but I'm struggling to write an expression that would detect if there are subdomains and get only the first one
Could someone show me the right expression?

Comment: Do you have any example code?

Comment: technically `www` is still a sub-domain of `google.com`. So `www.google.com` would evaluate to `www.google.com`.

Comment: it might be wiser to cut www. before preg replace

Comment: If you really wanted to do this, a single regex is likely not the correct way. You would want to break it up over a few steps. Match everything left of the first `/` if there is one to get the whole domain. Then explode on `.`. This will give you the domain broken up in parts in an array. Then work backwards through the array. The last value will be the "TLD" (`com`, but now there are tons of TLDs like `.ninja` or `.voyage` so don't try to match only a specific few). The next to last will be the "domain", `google`. The next one will be the first "subdomain". If that is `www`, stop, else keep.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't come up with a regex that does what you want, but as this question is only tagged with php here is some php code that does what you want.

This code will split your input by ".", extract the tld from the last part and shift everything up to 3 elements from the splitted string while ignoring a possible "www" part. Finally, it will combine the maximum 3 remaining parts, which gives you your desired domain with possibly one subdomain.

```
<?php
$domain = 'www.dev.maps.google.com/asd/fgh';
$parts = explode('.', $domain);

// extract tld
preg_match('/([a-z]+)[^a-z]/', $parts[count($parts)-1], $tldMatches);
$parts[count($parts)-1] = (isset($tldMatches[1])) 
    ? $tldMatches[1] 
    : $parts[count($parts)-1];

// remove www if present
if ('www' === $parts[0]) {
    array_shift($parts);
}

// define how many parts we have to ignore
$splitHere = (count($parts) > 3)
    ? count($parts) - 3
    : 0;

// output the desired parts combined with "."
echo implode('.', array_slice($parts, $splitHere)) . PHP_EOL;
```

This code will not work with umlaut-domains.

Answer (score 0):

Using regex-based methods to manipulate url strings is generally not recommended.  The first order of business is to prepare the string for `parse_url()`, then you will have a solid foundation to start from.

After generating a standardized `host` string, I use `explode()` and array functions to extract the desired result.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/b2c52ac1b0497defea2e2c402fcaaa1a5eb3cbcc))

```
$array=['google.com', // -> google.com
        'www.google.com', // -> google.com
        'www.maps.google.com', // -> maps.google.com
        'www.dev.maps.google.com', // - > maps.google.com
        'www.dev.maps.google.com/show/maps', // - > maps.google.com
        'www.dev.maps.google.com?key=value', // - > maps.google.com
];

foreach($array as $url){
    $host=parse_url("http://$url")['host'];        // reliable way to isolate host component only
    $bits=explode('.',$host);                      // split string on dots
    if($bits[0]==='www'){                          // check for www in first element
        unset($bits[0]);                           // remove first element
    }
    echo implode('.',array_slice($bits,-3)),"\n";  // extract maximum of 3 elements from end, rejoin with dots
}
```

Output:

```
google.com
google.com
maps.google.com
maps.google.com
maps.google.com
maps.google.com
```

This code is not written to validate the input string as a valid url.  It assumes you will be feeding valid domains to it.  If you *know* that the only substring to move after `www.` will be `dev.` then an approach can be written far more literally.